# How can I add Feature discovery in the app?

Tags: android, material-design

I'm trying to add [Feature discovery](https://material.io/archive/guidelines/growth-communications/feature-discovery.html#) to my app but there is no documentation about how to add that?

Is there any official way to add it instead of external libraries?